# unable use node run a javascript file in vscode, response with nothing, but can run a txt file in shell, and get response

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I tried run my js code in macOS bash,I brew install nodejs, then test in vscode, but the response is nothing. Instead, I copy javascript file content to a .txt file.  I run node text.txt, and it runs.

node test.js without response
node test.txt , it can print 999

```
console.log(999)
```

Comment: file permissions? by the way, if you omit the file extension nodejs will try to run a .js file as default, e.g. `nodejs test` will run test.js

Comment: I tried node test, but the same with node test.js. And I the command  line cant use nodejs, but node is ok

Answer (score 0):

Could there be an issue with file paths?  This isn't a common Node.js issue so I assume there is something about your development environment that's not quite right.  Are you sure you are running the bash from inside the same directory as the `test.js` file?

Comment: yeah, I create a new file named tree on my desktop, and test.js in tree, so I run node test.js under tree file in my terminal.  and node -v shows "v12.9.1"